# bind the managedObjectContext outlet for a controller using Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder

I'm trying to set up a fairly simple view that presents a table to the user. This table is connected to an Array Controller, which I want to use to retrieve records from Core Data. For some reason, I can't seem to connect the 'managedObjectContext' outlet to anything else in my app. When I created my project, there was a property generated in my app delegate which returns the MOC I need, but I can't hook it up in Interface Builder, even after prepending "IBOutlet" to the declaration. Image below showing the available connection on both ends:

http://yada.im/uploads/image/screenshot/1108/7efebc90ca7187a537da9ae003dd5f3e.png

I'm sure that I'm missing some simple step here but I can't tell what piece of glue code I'm supposed to write that will allow me to hook this up more easily. For reference, I've tried dragging a line from the controller's moc outlet to every single source I could think of, and changed the "File's Owner" class to that of my application. Stumped here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in the template provided by XCode the `managedObjectContext` comes along with `AppDelegate`. 
You have to bind the `managedObjectContext` reference of the array controller to the `managedObjectContext` in `AppDelegate`.

For this you have to make an object of `AppDelegate` inside the xib i.e., if its not already present.(Drag an object placeholder from your object library and make its class as `AppDelegate`)

This makes `AppDelegate` visible for binding inside that xib.

Next step is actually binding the managedObjectContext. Select your array controller and go to bindings inspector. In the parameters section select App Delegate from the drop down and check on "Bind to".
Fill the "Model Key Path" field with `self.managedObjectContext`. Now you will find the connection in the connections inspector also.

**UPDATE:**
The process of creating a new `AppDelegate` object is to be done only if it is not already present in the main nib file (but the stub generated always has the `AppDelegate` object in the main nib file).

For a non main nib file, if we follow the above approach, a new `AppDelegate` object will be created which won't be the `NSApplication's` delegate. Even though this can be solved by connecting delegate outlet of the application object proxy provided in each nib, the `AppDelegate` object still won't be the same.

The result is two different managedObjectContext talking to the same store. Although this might appear to work properly when the changes are saved at each step, this is not what we want.

**To get the right AppDelegate object, i.e. the one used in the main nib file:**
-instead of creating a new `AppDelegate` object, bind the `managedObjectContext` of the array controller directly through the application to its delegate. In other words the object to bind to will be the application object and the key path used will be `self.delegate.managedObjectContext`.

Comment: Additionally you would specify the entity you want to control with the array controller in the 'Object Controller' section of 'Identity Inspector'. You are all set to present your table after this.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That definitely got me closer to making this table come to life. Now I'm trying to figure out how to make the prebaked actions on the controller work. I've hooked up buttons to add: and remove: but I'm not sure how to extend their functionality to, say, slide a sheet into view for the user to enter the text for the new entity. Feeling generous?

Comment: Note that you are not adding entities through the array controller but objects, i.e, managed objects (of class NSManagedObject).

Comment: I've added another answer. Check if that helps.

Comment: If you make an app delegate object in a XIB that is not designated as the main NIB in Info.plist (NSMainNib), then you will create a separate app delegate object that is not the app delegate you want, and will not have the managedObjectContext you want.

Comment: @stevesliva: yes you are right. But that was not the OP's problem. He was not able to do it in the main nib itself. Moreover the nib has the MainMenu also, which typically will to be in the main nib. So it's a safe assumption to make. Nevertheless I will edit the answer in case others need help on a non-main nib file.

Answer (score 0):

The way to add objects of your entity depends on the specific logic you want to implement.
The generic and easy solution would be, **binding the fields for input to the array controller** like you might have done for the table and then hooking up the array controller methods to the buttons inside the sheet.  
  
Another option is sub-classing NSArrayController and over-riding the super class methods like `add:` to write your code (for opening your slide sheet maybe) before calling the super class method, `[super add:sender]` . Don't forget to specify this sub-class of NSArrayController as the class of your array controller in the xib.